# Exemplo de Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Como faço para adicionar uma *Navigation Drawer* a uma *Activity*? Procurei em vários sites porém só achei os projetos para *download* e não a explicação de como fazê-lo.

Comment: Tente este [link](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer).